Is there a global formula to remove coefficient of $(x+y+z)^n$?
I'm looking for a formula to remove the coefficient of $(x+y+z)^n$
For example by analogy :
$(x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2$ and to remove the coefficient $2$ you can use $(x^3-y^3)/(x-y) = x^2+xy+y^2$
$(x+y)^3 = x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$ and to remove the coefficient $3$ you can use $(x^4-y^4)/(x-y) = x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3$
and so to remove the coefficient of $(x+y)^{(n-1)}$ you can use $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$.
But what if we use $(x+y+z)^n ?$
Is there a global formula to remove the coefficiant of polynomials with three variables of this kind ?
I tried to work with $(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz$ and find a formula to remove the $2$ but I failed.

When you say "the" coefficient, what do you clearly mean, what is "the" coefficient among all coefficients of the polynom. ?

@EDX, I mean remove all coefficients to 1, for example $x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz$

In other words, you want a closed form for $\sum_{i+j+k=n} x^iy^jz^k$? (The sum is over all triples $i,j,k$ that add up to $n$.)

Misha, yes, but I don't know if it's possible.

@Sil Yes ! Thanks !
So now what should I do ? maybe put this question as a duplicate ?
Nevermind I did it, thanks all for your help !
